# SSRS workflow report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Without going into too much detail, I need to create a report based on a workflow process. every job has a begin time, one or more work events, and an end time. The job itself is stored in one table, and the events (including start time, end time, and any other events) are stored in another table. My reports needs a single line for each job to show when it started, and when specified events occurred. No problem so far.

However, it is possible that a job has more than one start and end time. For example, if a job started, then it was discovered there was an equipment issue, the worker could return, fix the issue, then leave again. In this case, the report would need a separate line for each Start/End period. so, something like:

```
 Job# 2b    Job start 10am       work done      Job end 11am

 Job# 2b    Job start 1pm        work done      Job end 3pm
```

Not sure what the best approach would be to accomplish this.

Comment: Can you give the specific structure of the `events` table?

Comment: Basically, it's a GUID(pk), a Job ID (fk), a datetime, and a description text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, your data seems like this:

```
create table Jobs
(
  jobID int
  , jobName varchar(100)
)

create table Events
(
  jobID int
  , eventDate datetime
  , eventText varchar(100)
)

insert into Jobs select 1, 'Job1'
insert into Jobs select 2, 'Job2'

insert into Events select 1, '01-jan-2013 10:00', 'Start'
insert into Events select 1, '01-jan-2013 10:30', 'Work'
insert into Events select 1, '01-jan-2013 11:00', 'End'

insert into Events select 2, '01-jan-2013 10:00', 'Start'
insert into Events select 2, '01-jan-2013 10:10', 'Work'
insert into Events select 2, '01-jan-2013 10:20', 'End'
insert into Events select 2, '01-jan-2013 10:30', 'Start'
insert into Events select 2, '01-jan-2013 10:40', 'Work'
insert into Events select 2, '01-jan-2013 10:50', 'End'
insert into Events select 2, '01-jan-2013 11:00', 'Start'
insert into Events select 2, '01-jan-2013 11:10', 'Work'
```

What you want to get is one row per start/end combination. You can do this by selecting the *Start* rows, and joining back to the `Events` table to get the subsequent *End* row:

```
select j.jobName, startDate = e.eventDate, endDate = endEvent.eventDate
from Jobs j
  inner join Events e on j.jobID = e.jobID
  outer apply
  (
    select top 1 ee.eventDate
    from Events ee
    where e.jobID = ee.jobID
      and e.eventDate < ee.eventDate
      and ee.eventText = 'End'
    order by ee.eventDate
  ) endEvent
where e.eventText = 'Start'
```

Gives results:

```
JOBNAME STARTDATE                         ENDDATE
Job1    January, 01 2013 10:00:00+0000    January, 01 2013 11:00:00+0000
Job2    January, 01 2013 10:00:00+0000    January, 01 2013 10:20:00+0000
Job2    January, 01 2013 10:30:00+0000    January, 01 2013 10:50:00+0000
Job2    January, 01 2013 11:00:00+0000    (null)
```

[SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/51409/1).

You should be able to adapt to your data/tables.

Once you have this final result set, you can easily add use this as the Dataset for a standard SSRS table.

Comment: Thanks very much! I think I'll be able to get that to do what I need!